# how to use an argument passed from the main class to another class within another function?

Tags: java, function, class, arguments, parameter-passing

I try to make a game of blackjack and I ran into an issue with the functions. I want to pass arguments of money and bet, check the winner and calculate the new sum of money and then pass it to another function (in the same class) to return the value since functions can return only 1 value and I can't find a way to do it.

```
package project1;

public class RestultsNPayment {
        //int cash;
    public static String winner(int Dtotal, int Ptotal, int money, int bet) {
        if(Ptotal > 21) {
            return ("--------Dealer wins--------");
                        cash = money;
        }
        else if (Ptotal == Dtotal)
            return ("------------Tie------------");
        else {
            if(21-Ptotal > 21-Dtotal && Dtotal < 22)
                return ("--------Dealer wins--------");
            else
                return ("--------Player wins--------");
        }
    }
    public static int payment(int money, int bet) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I tried to to use this. method and create variable that will hold it. tried to make a new function that will get money and bet but then realized I need to find the winner first so I don't think it will help. I thought about getting money and bet in the winner function, calculate the new amount of cash and then pass cash into the payment function. please correct me if this is wrong thinking or you have a better way of doing it.

Comment: The reason for objects in general is to bundle a small amount of data with the methods which use it, so the data is not passed as parameters. Looks like you're treating a class as just a namespace for some functions.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want to pass where, and what you want to return from where. It is true functions only return one value, but that value does not have to be a simple value. It can be a class.

Answer (score 0):

From reading your question, what you're trying to implement is not difficult, but it can be very confusing to correctly implement if you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how Java code is structured. There are a couple of mix-ups in your code.

To start, a method (or function) is a set of instructions that can be called for execution (invocation) by another part of your program by referencing the method name. A method can take input (any number of parameters) and either produces a return value or nothing. The keyword "void" indicates that the method returns null (which is a keyword used to denote the absence of a value).

Each method should typically only have a single, clear, specific purpose (documentation also helps). Additionally, to execute your code, the statements you want executed should be inside a class that contains a main method. For simplicity, I have added it in the existing class.

In the 'winner' method, the arguments 'money' and 'bet' are never used, so those can be omitted. Additionally, you are trying to set the value of the nonlocal variable 'cash' inside this method, which will result in a compilation error. Here is an updated version of the method:

```
public static String winner(int Dtotal, int Ptotal) {
    if (Ptotal > 21) {
        return "dealer";
    } else if (Ptotal == Dtotal) {
        return "tie";
    } else {
        if (21 - Ptotal > 21 - Dtotal && Dtotal < 22) {
            return "dealer";
        } else {
            return "player";
    }
}
```

Now it is clear that this method's sole purpose is to evaluate the winner. After determining the winner, your next steps are to calculate the new amount of cash and then pass the cash into the payment method. However, as the explanation was ambiguous, I'm not exactly sure what it is you're looking to achieve; so I will leave an example solution.

Full code:

```
package project1;

public class RestultsNPayment {

    public static String winner(int Dtotal, int Ptotal) {
        if (Ptotal > 21) {
            return "dealer";
        } else if (Ptotal == Dtotal) {
            return "tie";
        } else {
            if (21 - Ptotal > 21 - Dtotal && Dtotal < 22) {
                return "dealer";
            } else {
                return "player";
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static int payment(int cash) {
        return 0;
    }

    // Where your code is executed
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Holds the return value of the winner method
        String champion = winner(10, 20);  // Arbitrary Dtotal and Ptotal arguments

        // [Insert logic to calculate cash here]
        int cash = 0;

        // Passing cash into payment method
        payment(cash);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!